# What does the GCC function suffix "isra" mean?

Tags: gcc, profiling, name-mangling

While profiling a program compiled with gcc, I noticed functions like `foo.isra.3`. What does `isra` indicate? I notice that one of the functions is only called in a few places, and one of the arguments is always specified as a literal value. Maybe it means it's a variant of the function optimised for certain arguments?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to a comment on [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42290) (and similar comments I could find):

> ISRA is the name of the variable that gets created by IPA SRA ...

IPA SRA is an [optimization option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> **-fipa-sra**
>
> Perform interprocedural scalar replacement of aggregates, removal of unused parameters and replacement of parameters passed by reference by parameters passed by value.
>
> Enabled at levels -O2, -O3 and -Os.

So most likely, it's a version of a function with those optimizations.

In the case you mentioned, it's possible that it's replacing a pass-by-reference with a pass-by-value since it knows there's no point to passing a literal by reference.