# What does the GCC function suffix .constprop mean?

Tags: gcc, name-mangling

Looking at the disassembly of a C++ program, I see functions like `_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii.constprop.221`. What does the `constprop` mean in this case? It appears to be similar in appearance to the [isra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963150/what-does-the-gcc-function-suffix-isra-mean) suffix (and is sometimes combined, e.g. `.isra.124.constprop.226`), but it means something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From source code comments I've read - they indicate functions which have been cloned during optimization.

**EDIT**: This may be the answer, maybe not.

> Simple constant propagation
>
> This file implements constant propagation and merging. It looks for instructions involving only constant operands and replaces them with a constant value instead of an instruction. For example:
>
> ```
> add i32 1, 2
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> i32 3
> ```
>
> NOTE: this pass has a habit of making definitions be dead. It is a good idea to to run a DIE (Dead Instruction Elimination) pass sometime after running this pass.

[SOURCE](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html)

Comment: Do you happen to know what optimization is being performed?

Comment: Cool. It looks like it might be interprocedure constant propagation since it creates multiple versions of the functions. Though the document is for LLVM, I guess a similar thing must apply to GCC.

Comment: Always fun to resurrect an old thread. :) I'm not a gcc dev, but I will add a few things to this. If you have a static function and you happen to call it with a certain constant (or constants) for one or some of its parameter(s), gcc can create an optimized version just for that combination of parameter value(s). This phenomena can be exploited in very interesting ways.

Comment: @DanielSantos Thanks, this helped me figure out why my `always_inline` function was not inlined, but `call`-ed.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Depending upon what you're trying to do, this can be a problem and is the reason the `flatten` function attribute was added. If you defined the *calling* function with this attribute, it should force the inlining (of everything that it can). I *think* that the reason it isn't doing it is because the compiler thinks that the constant-propagated version is better. I had this discussion with a gcc dev some time back, but I can't remember all of the nuances.