# What is "isra" in the kernel thread dump

Tags: linux-kernel

Linux kernel call stack dump often includes function names that ends with ".isra.NNN" where NNN is some numbers. For example, see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1324638#p1324638) and [here](http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/unexpected-Out-Of-Memory-OOM-td5718038.html).

What does that mean, what does the number signify?

Comment: I think this could be related to ftrace and inlined functions.  The NNN would be the offset into the inlined function.

Comment: This thread should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963150/what-does-the-gcc-function-suffix-isra-mean

Comment: Answered in LKML: https://www.spinics.net/lists/gcchelp/msg27678.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> `isra` is the suffix added to the function name when `gcc` option `-fipa-sra` compiler optimization being carried out.

From [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

```
-fipa-sra
```

> Perform interprocedural scalar replacement of aggregates, removal of unused
>       parameters and replacement of parameters passed by reference by parameters passed
>       by value.
>
> Enabled at levels `-O2`, `-O3` and `-Os`.

All functions that are optimized under this option have `isra` appended to their names. I digged into `gcc` code and found out the function that was appending the string.

```
tree
clone_function_name (tree decl, const char *suffix)
{
  tree name = DECL_ASSEMBLER_NAME (decl);
  size_t len = IDENTIFIER_LENGTH (name);
  char *tmp_name, *prefix;

  prefix = XALLOCAVEC (char, len + strlen (suffix) + 2);
  memcpy (prefix, IDENTIFIER_POINTER (name), len);
  strcpy (prefix + len + 1, suffix);
#ifndef NO_DOT_IN_LABEL
  prefix[len] = '.';
#elif !defined NO_DOLLAR_IN_LABEL
  prefix[len] = '$';
#else
  prefix[len] = '_';
#endif
  ASM_FORMAT_PRIVATE_NAME (tmp_name, prefix, clone_fn_id_num++);
  return get_identifier (tmp_name);
}
```

Here, argument 2, `const char *suffix`, is `"isra"` and notice at the bottom of the function macro `ASM_FORMAT_PRIVATE_NAME` which takes `clone_fn_id_num++` as its 3rd argument. This is the arbitrary number found after `"isra"`. This going by its name is the count of functions that are cloned under this compiler option (or may be a global counter that keeps track of all cloned functions).

If you want to understand more, search for `modify_function` in file `gcc/tree-sra.c` which in turn calls `cgraph_function_versioning()` which passes `"isra"` as its last argument.

Comment: `-fipa-src`: do you mean `-fipa-sra`?