# What does it mean when "perf top" shows me a symbol like __lock_acquire.isra.27

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

Here's a snippet from the output of "perf top" run on a system running linux 3.13. I'm trying to find the kernel code corresponding to __lock_acquire.isra.27. I've been able to find a static routine named __lock_acquire in kernel/source/lockdep.c but nothing about "isra". I have a similar experience with lock_release_holdtime.part.17

```
  7.98%  [kernel]                 [k] __lock_acquire.isra.27
  2.70%  [kernel]                 [k] lock_release
  2.56%  [kernel]                 [k] lock_release_holdtime.part.17
  2.29%  [kernel]                 [k] local_clock
  2.27%  [kernel]                 [k] lock_acquired
  2.14%  [kernel]                 [k] sched_clock_cpu
  2.14%  [kernel]                 [k] lock_acquire
```

This smells like some type of symbol mangling - but this is plain vanilla C.

Routines I've found can be seen at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/lockdep.c?v=3.13

My guess is there's a general rule here I've completely missed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Perform interprocedural scalar replacement **-fipa-sra** -- "... All functions that are optimized under this option have "isra" appended to their names" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907580/what-is-isra-in-the-kernel-thread-dump, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963150/what-does-the-gcc-function-suffix-isra-mean

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907580/what-is-isra-in-the-kernel-thread-dump/18914402#18914402

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907580/what-is-isra-in-the-kernel-thread-dump