# What is do_cos_slow.isra?

Tags: glibc, avx, perf, trigonometry

I wrote a simple code to test for `prof`.

```
double bar_compute (double d) {
    double t = std::abs(d);
    t += std::sqrt(d);
    t += std::cos(d);

    return t;
}

// Do some computation n times
double foo_compute(unsigned n) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);

    double total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        double d = dist(mt);
        total += bar_compute(d);
    }
    return total;
}
```

When I run `prof` and view the output it is

```
  56.14%  runcode  libm-2.23.so       [.] __cos_avx                                                                                                                                
  27.34%  runcode  runcode            [.] _Z11foo_computej                                                                                                                         
  13.92%  runcode  runcode            [.] _Z11bar_computed                                                                                                                         
   0.86%  runcode  libm-2.23.so       [.] do_cos_slow.isra.1                                                                                                                       
   0.44%  runcode  runcode            [.] cos@plt                                                                                                                                  
   0.41%  runcode  libm-2.23.so       [.] sloww1                                                                                                                                   
   0.35%  runcode  libm-2.23.so       [.] __dubcos                                                                                                                                 
   0.17%  runcode  ld-2.23.so         [.] _dl_lookup_symbol_x
```

What is `do_cos_slow.isra` and `sloww1` mean?

Is there a faster version of `cos` that I can use? Otherwise why would it be called slow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`do_cos_slow` comes from its declaration in [glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c#L167). It is called `do_cos_slow` because it is more precise than the function it is based on `do_cos` as per the comment above its declaration on [Line 164](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c#L164).

The `.isra` is because the function is version which has been optimised by IPA SRA as per the following [Stack Overflow Answer, What does the GCC function suffix “isra” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963150/what-does-the-gcc-function-suffix-isra-mean)

`sloww1` is a function that computes sin(x+dx) as per the comment above it.

Regarding a faster version of cos, I am not sure if there is a faster version, but if you update your glibc or libc implementation that provides libm, to at least glibc 2.28, then you will get the results of Wilco Dijkstra's removal of these slowpath functions and refactor of dosincos which gives a speed boost.

From the [commit message](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=e88ecbbfe836db5b6da809108759de4ca56be5e7)

```
Refactor the sincos implementation - rather than rely on odd partial inlining
of preprocessed portions from sin and cos, explicitly write out the cases.
This makes sincos much easier to maintain and provides an additional 16-20%
speedup between 0 and 2^27.  The overall speedup of sincos is 48% over this range.
Between 0 and PI it is 66% faster.
```

Other alternatives you can try are other libc or libm implementations, or other cos implementations including [avx_mathfun](http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/) or [avx_mathfun with some fixes for newer GCC](https://github.com/reyoung/avx_mathfun) or [supersimd](https://bitbucket.org/pzam/supersimd/).